# How to provide a Leaflet GeoJSON feature collection to turf.centroid?

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I would like to find the centroid of a group of polygons, where each polygon represents a farm field. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
        $('#field-group').multiselect({
            nonSelectedText: 'Choose Field(s):',
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                var fieldList=[];
                $('option:selected', $('#field-group')).each(function() {
                    // fieldList.push({value:$(this).val(),text:$(this).text()});
                    fieldList.push($(this).val());
                });

                var queryString = $.param({field_name__exact:fieldList}, true);

                var centroid;
                fields = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'fields' %}?"+queryString, {
                    style: { color: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.0},
                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                        //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description.toString());
                        centroid = turf.centroid(feature);
                        var lon = centroid.geometry.coordinates[0];
                        var lat = centroid.geometry.coordinates[1];
                        map.setView([lat, lon], 14)
                    }
                }).addTo(map);
            }
        });
```

The map pans to the centroid of last field added, which is not what I want. However, I can't seem to get it to pan to the centroid of the Feature Collection. I have tried using this:

```
        $('#field-group').multiselect({
            nonSelectedText: 'Choose Field(s):',
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                var fieldList=[];
                $('option:selected', $('#field-group')).each(function() {
                    // fieldList.push({value:$(this).val(),text:$(this).text()});
                    fieldList.push($(this).val());
                });

                var queryString = $.param({field_name__exact:fieldList}, true);

                var centroid;
                fields = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'fields' %}?"+queryString, {
                    style: { color: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.0},
                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                        //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description.toString());
                    }
                }).addTo(map);

                var test = fields.toGetJSON() // make a Feature Collection
                centroid = turf.centroid(test); // takes a Feature Collection
                var lon = centroid.geometry.coordinates[0];
                var lat = centroid.geometry.coordinates[1];
                map.setView([lat, lon], 14)
            }
        });
```

But with this code, I get a 'Uncaught Error: coordinates must contain numbers'. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone advise please?

Here is the GeoJSON feature collection I would like to get the centroid of:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"client_nam": "MSFF", "farm_name": "Lauderdale", "field_name": "064", "polygontyp": 0, "shape_leng": 6403.54792475, "shape_area": 2500990.45035, "area_ac": 618.008199278, "farm": 0, "grower": 1, "pk": "2"}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-89.89392924524434, 35.69692900010964], [-89.89397896493877, 35.69693891373261], [-89.89399774773102, 35.69694972946372], [-89.89406293561315, 35.696974063403445], [-89.89413475280982, 35.69698578042825], [-89.89513577562231, 35.69707680953917], [-89.89515787422303, 35.69707861278143], [-89.89561750436316, 35.69710655119105], [-89.89564402249842, 35.69710835519184], [-89.89579207576386, 35.69712637962693], [-89.89683398047805, 35.69721831004002], [-89.89686712670081, 35.69721831021136], [-89.89709252256554, 35.697246250628424], [-89.8971245633863, 35.697247151586424], [-89.8973676380404, 35.697264275799874], [-89.89740520383717, 35.69726607824239], [-89.89792891817353, 35.69731384653144], [-89.89795101564596, 35.69731384584378], [-89.89899291882548, 35.697400368743054], [-89.89901501694698, 35.697401270013415], [-89.89909346354239, 35.69741659245474], [-89.89916749031224, 35.69741839419948], [-89.89928350312223, 35.6974310129386], [-89.8994691231003, 35.69744362987771], [-89.89949453575302, 35.697442728829], [-89.89985583120854, 35.697479680993375], [-89.90027679129888, 35.69751483098848], [-89.90191533231281, 35.697651826118836], [-89.90193963914663, 35.69765272673085], [-89.90422674478353, 35.69785371257284], [-89.90425105193212, 35.69785641614321], [-89.90649727673167, 35.69804388296781], [-89.9065392630568, 35.698042079694346], [-89.90702651593764, 35.69807182205378], [-89.90705082254311, 35.698073624700754], [-89.90739886149775, 35.69810607067188], [-89.90742427341385, 35.69810697229438], [-89.90794798698916, 35.69814662845909], [-89.90845954718644, 35.69817637118887], [-89.90850153345474, 35.69817727192989], [-89.90887387745295, 35.69818898792924], [-89.90890039505622, 35.6981880870011], [-89.90891807295093, 35.69820160653022], [-89.9089700030801, 35.69824937398365], [-89.90895563914198, 35.69827370860559], [-89.90894238118688, 35.698378257112324], [-89.90894238083057, 35.69839718371234], [-89.90893354203203, 35.69844044467485], [-89.90891144476537, 35.69861529394119], [-89.90886503945832, 35.69892262963565], [-89.9087655989153, 35.69959858878641], [-89.90876338976926, 35.699622924129216], [-89.9085711413809, 35.70084776272312], [-89.90856782604114, 35.70087480067237], [-89.9080419019526, 35.70429605630674], [-89.90803748178027, 35.7043248982493], [-89.90795461558803, 35.70478364910501], [-89.90789384742043, 35.705188323173424], [-89.90762757091309, 35.70710534475526], [-89.90762315211987, 35.7071278768855], [-89.9075844808395, 35.70730362587183], [-89.90758779569457, 35.707324355947996], [-89.90758448133349, 35.70739375422304], [-89.9075634882039, 35.70754607097185], [-89.90746073472926, 35.70823464732061], [-89.9072905826364, 35.70928193439962], [-89.9072894773355, 35.70930266318926], [-89.90715136819534, 35.710229179069685], [-89.90714915672828, 35.71024990846188], [-89.90647959977048, 35.71453368916356], [-89.90645860599905, 35.71454360310321], [-89.90640336149664, 35.71454360271376], [-89.90632712584683, 35.714532787955854], [-89.90593489302691, 35.7145039465292], [-89.90542664711816, 35.71447510585435], [-89.90435601582725, 35.71441021411642], [-89.90021270870528, 35.71415244792596], [-89.90016851292069, 35.714148842590795], [-89.89414138257374, 35.71376399734617], [-89.89411597010145, 35.71376309483678], [-89.89221004898428, 35.713653139423826], [-89.89217690311492, 35.713648632668345], [-89.89169075409323, 35.71360807501945], [-89.89167639026059, 35.71359185240414], [-89.89167639091588, 35.71355399909158], [-89.89168743993552, 35.713508033647635], [-89.89172832058478, 35.7132592800101], [-89.8917305295669, 35.713233143263324], [-89.8917614668002, 35.71295915435798], [-89.8918940526648, 35.711935301224926], [-89.89221225899834, 35.709628927164225], [-89.89220010485218, 35.70961090208179], [-89.8923072780561, 35.708815972655245], [-89.89238351477313, 35.70817606467339], [-89.89238351461397, 35.70814632278711], [-89.89241334681158, 35.7079858949243], [-89.89246306712592, 35.7076434090494], [-89.89246306734469, 35.70762358021529], [-89.89250615691903, 35.70744602838808], [-89.89250615777065, 35.70742169409251], [-89.89252162582412, 35.7072783906253], [-89.89252825393596, 35.70725675935841], [-89.89256250652191, 35.707026032463844], [-89.89256361186202, 35.70699719139074], [-89.89259565271125, 35.70670878235815], [-89.89266084029182, 35.706156298066496], [-89.89266194606505, 35.706135568406005], [-89.89277574909512, 35.70528025432009], [-89.89277795814698, 35.705260425525275], [-89.89343536294747, 35.700285363804724], [-89.89343757236203, 35.70026643715484], [-89.89388284038843, 35.696993891451505], [-89.89388615396734, 35.69697406308933], [-89.89390493749985, 35.69693711149333], [-89.89392924524434, 35.69692900010964]]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"client_nam": "MSFF", "farm_name": "Lauderdale", "field_name": "053", "polygontyp": 0, "shape_leng": 10388.1939987, "shape_area": 2702155.83411, "area_ac": 667.729728166, "farm": 0, "grower": 1, "pk": "1"}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-89.86060511911957, 35.686488718320284], [-89.8606946589609, 35.6865061205794], [-89.86077092887423, 35.686534997107344], [-89.86087390624193, 35.68664136043166], [-89.86102641730923, 35.68679397718338], [-89.86111563659816, 35.68686107158934], [-89.8612449626168, 35.68687261691992], [-89.86134725883414, 35.686866848883355], [-89.86146301554896, 35.686868199721594], [-89.86162415600155, 35.68687257522511], [-89.86178529752841, 35.686876949584985], [-89.86195678568744, 35.68688928641177], [-89.86209560024024, 35.68690240131702], [-89.86227860687073, 35.68695550607839], [-89.86241215506962, 35.68703236092858], [-89.86254155652192, 35.68713393996], [-89.86272166334875, 35.68724662450333], [-89.8629468636845, 35.68735413289169], [-89.86298551522484, 35.6873798899144], [-89.86309778566167, 35.68742441589675], [-89.8632101295819, 35.687470993135705], [-89.86347346959133, 35.687589904132544], [-89.86371240996301, 35.68772991664179], [-89.86378742280553, 35.687787642222624], [-89.86391519401468, 35.68791388505358], [-89.86396551336874, 35.68798451080842], [-89.86399743335353, 35.688033002094436], [-89.86402188652336, 35.68808372246544], [-89.8640685924546, 35.68812365373161], [-89.86412520526521, 35.68815924376366], [-89.86420739113244, 35.68820653811011], [-89.86418743525888, 35.688256082508744], [-89.86427064148921, 35.68828758193634], [-89.86437023451838, 35.68829916037972], [-89.86450380015556, 35.68830434990677], [-89.86469505641104, 35.68829700483276], [-89.86486922772414, 35.688290067268724], [-89.86505806410379, 35.68831068013206], [-89.86517202532495, 35.688341446382026], [-89.86525543262334, 35.68837852014156], [-89.86535350416558, 35.68844314540221], [-89.86547931338545, 35.6885182712439], [-89.8655983876962, 35.688596345949776], [-89.86564712438954, 35.68862029629761], [-89.86569224517979, 35.68863875205435], [-89.86574419973047, 35.688657044082575], [-89.86584429344377, 35.68868256024541], [-89.86601302768106, 35.68871481104317], [-89.86613674200389, 35.68873139398575], [-89.8662567394727, 35.688739694295286], [-89.86636960267423, 35.688739795221956], [-89.86649321615366, 35.68875358984033], [-89.8665897940502, 35.6887763997012], [-89.86666938459017, 35.68880240378432], [-89.86674645723576, 35.68885357742887], [-89.86681981308108, 35.68889647033742], [-89.86687558590815, 35.68892583138897], [-89.86695497702469, 35.68894626021764], [-89.86702803462599, 35.688980789032556], [-89.86712169355553, 35.68901761800925], [-89.8672890420594, 35.68907419396012], [-89.86737364640419, 35.68908591266296], [-89.8674644881373, 35.68908374713922], [-89.86757532002876, 35.689075610798945], [-89.86769683632293, 35.689083702201785], [-89.86775076611491, 35.689085163558424], [-89.8677984597358, 35.68910050994574], [-89.86784605387861, 35.68911310978824], [-89.8680155589152, 35.689144781461344], [-89.8681347914951, 35.68918314580819], [-89.86820940096827, 35.68919784933195], [-89.86832576682083, 35.68921490714187], [-89.86859116407138, 35.689232699074594], [-89.86898727174238, 35.68929193020028], [-89.86935081628141, 35.68938215571749], [-89.86954050809182, 35.68941334365991], [-89.86968606821152, 35.6894345939997], [-89.8697972938299, 35.68943743548149], [-89.86987121499494, 35.689432924730504], [-89.86995829771003, 35.68941985772478], [-89.87003172793251, 35.68940162312501], [-89.8701323669081, 35.68939098053155], [-89.87030366306867, 35.68937865181604], [-89.87051285300379, 35.689390142388305], [-89.87065158595384, 35.689408809187455], [-89.87089586942255, 35.68945213014719], [-89.87108069323645, 35.68945608888516], [-89.87126591699914, 35.68947119830231], [-89.87135877831247, 35.68948572193019], [-89.87147626070762, 35.68951918839368], [-89.8715831908285, 35.689544536499824], [-89.87173494355137, 35.68957997400866], [-89.87186177637118, 35.68958810728184], [-89.87201926297726, 35.68959271725387], [-89.8721765495315, 35.68959175109087], [-89.87239876115058, 35.68958923432663], [-89.87254609761568, 35.68959687634379], [-89.87282448361059, 35.68963486893609], [-89.87321833639378, 35.68974543417038], [-89.87403276179028, 35.68999828346813], [-89.87421970655774, 35.69001167799909], [-89.87440180920525, 35.69003141306212], [-89.87461213669195, 35.69005058867938], [-89.8747733537813, 35.6900790040906], [-89.87485698458303, 35.69009475231329], [-89.87495345485259, 35.690137623024874], [-89.87506172470056, 35.69017859743398], [-89.87515238336009, 35.69022483345893], [-89.87523926407296, 35.69027599957123], [-89.87542605448324, 35.69030057621788], [-89.8756556723272, 35.69036123691002], [-89.87585826429216, 35.69044029214132], [-89.87597350507605, 35.6905101408395], [-89.87603021724192, 35.6906023633716], [-89.87639217533429, 35.69065824493519], [-89.8765886672787, 35.69073260402028], [-89.8768280456112, 35.69084465854801], [-89.87708096826725, 35.69094832129559], [-89.877280132745, 35.69104197738382], [-89.87740450167269, 35.69109063092339], [-89.87764388883825, 35.69114782835269], [-89.87795778699251, 35.691187106985794], [-89.87826168898012, 35.69122339832955], [-89.87859220739821, 35.69128486532512], [-89.87885414915937, 35.69130925128496], [-89.87973389238896, 35.6914091989683], [-89.88010742133278, 35.69145672574608], [-89.88085698051509, 35.69156623540072], [-89.881567983484, 35.69168288100922], [-89.88218226943944, 35.69173616411603], [-89.8823475598165, 35.69176769816228], [-89.88264960431174, 35.69180724846502], [-89.8831265893698, 35.6918716474421], [-89.88369587013536, 35.69191769627419], [-89.8839266618043, 35.69195572592516], [-89.88408003861157, 35.6919859299263], [-89.88446304586341, 35.69202192189544], [-89.88497165016888, 35.69203069831448], [-89.88545479897394, 35.69210139233426], [-89.88595177983892, 35.692171754310614], [-89.88645050476903, 35.692235617439245], [-89.8869671900793, 35.6923038881254], [-89.88732956832847, 35.692371020095266], [-89.88812133698858, 35.69249883181376], [-89.88851312494694, 35.692558801774545], [-89.8886778382622, 35.69257420628703], [-89.8903451362773, 35.69284876897063], [-89.89097778041891, 35.69295134366992], [-89.89123850951746, 35.69299670591291], [-89.89173730478555, 35.69311701520721], [-89.89272246137278, 35.69334179285705], [-89.89335313993615, 35.6934992579868], [-89.89389087978094, 35.693602486786126], [-89.89406193156724, 35.69362902605112], [-89.8942591378404, 35.693667843707864], [-89.89430186065628, 35.693700697114416], [-89.8943086044927, 35.69372312247514], [-89.89430412258174, 35.69375420519145], [-89.89430724750487, 35.69384062222175], [-89.89431135513112, 35.69390859904202], [-89.89428638104589, 35.694209409603864], [-89.8943033808118, 35.69434441370987], [-89.89430246620124, 35.694483189007734], [-89.89421406168962, 35.69530409526072], [-89.89419310338371, 35.69566543308508], [-89.89416706885885, 35.69601744052072], [-89.89414327458262, 35.69669901199647], [-89.89413932864902, 35.69675396366155], [-89.89411137475365, 35.69684184412398], [-89.8940889651422, 35.69688423384472], [-89.89404544665035, 35.69691039129965], [-89.89367552318956, 35.69689096953977], [-89.89289266115796, 35.69684687897401], [-89.89285110359684, 35.69684626526559], [-89.89272422072922, 35.696838023213154], [-89.89263500169629, 35.69683210174333], [-89.89214281458212, 35.69678585483037], [-89.89050629764746, 35.69665417363725], [-89.88803060864572, 35.69645227256077], [-89.88640026308855, 35.6963268408669], [-89.88606902191083, 35.69630090727561], [-89.88605373743238, 35.69648036405855], [-89.88598965775927, 35.6970391403147], [-89.88588405035371, 35.69773459679528], [-89.88581753065476, 35.69821971641829], [-89.88571466436643, 35.69899125272329], [-89.8856338790951, 35.69959854665558], [-89.88556529887127, 35.699897159430535], [-89.88550467451857, 35.70028695585259], [-89.88549726746831, 35.700340434791286], [-89.88543252759746, 35.700357216814105], [-89.88535165212551, 35.70034457002918], [-89.88417653504946, 35.700216016129154], [-89.88324585782865, 35.70009374541399], [-89.88212761700775, 35.699960553260865], [-89.8811246961461, 35.69984752099631], [-89.88110228135318, 35.699838208839665], [-89.88075463712201, 35.69981069805273], [-89.87977517296646, 35.69970089954987], [-89.87752533769222, 35.69943874533986], [-89.8767612227664, 35.6993466132033], [-89.87650322559399, 35.69931090446271], [-89.87643394265905, 35.69946104553885], [-89.87642673687841, 35.69965437630385], [-89.87638106345948, 35.70000143543319], [-89.8761928580837, 35.70123635166785], [-89.8761067531427, 35.70179084238757], [-89.87602507629799, 35.70227826607298], [-89.87594964364176, 35.70265393649595], [-89.87592862554759, 35.70273535189654], [-89.87589001853567, 35.70280323617053], [-89.87582698658173, 35.702857753668226], [-89.87573279500025, 35.70290185753599], [-89.87567891378627, 35.70292546686227], [-89.8752026446677, 35.70299823440624], [-89.87467470801424, 35.7030610764057], [-89.87416054257581, 35.7031263755334], [-89.87384741740627, 35.70317013013691], [-89.8735884742579, 35.7031986375995], [-89.87348292666135, 35.70321231996372], [-89.87341115562828, 35.70321403475685], [-89.87332873114326, 35.703204843549486], [-89.87318919313171, 35.703216048984125], [-89.87303573951904, 35.70322391038958], [-89.87303849169238, 35.7031705423457], [-89.8730749127264, 35.70303398353932], [-89.87310538619468, 35.70287309899705], [-89.87312222422784, 35.70277258492997], [-89.87315420599927, 35.70262333765406], [-89.87318020642765, 35.70254310779182], [-89.87318489101851, 35.702515155494424], [-89.87320434217992, 35.702432152045425], [-89.87322127829238, 35.702340282452184], [-89.87325847158523, 35.70217296625936], [-89.87327381834152, 35.7020395461986], [-89.87327827150342, 35.70193923876493], [-89.87326976074037, 35.70187045219974], [-89.87325133931384, 35.70177808260826], [-89.87322900789022, 35.70171701757577], [-89.87317619310404, 35.701508022682084], [-89.87314702962287, 35.70142494497338], [-89.87310914546966, 35.701295260655336], [-89.8730501729076, 35.70111105184439], [-89.8730140008475, 35.701001038372915], [-89.87297256053392, 35.70091250464662], [-89.8729469472724, 35.700844126583625], [-89.8729273349139, 35.70080270741235], [-89.87290278235469, 35.70076387123315], [-89.87285420647572, 35.700700968931336], [-89.87259383305899, 35.70043204685169], [-89.87250297980721, 35.70034140889306], [-89.87247292014251, 35.70031748686476], [-89.87243860195663, 35.700287096238995], [-89.87240150230123, 35.70026334323129], [-89.87237046645221, 35.70024026645311], [-89.87233235887528, 35.70021653659359], [-89.87228505034899, 35.70018892024843], [-89.87224197316563, 35.700166952969425], [-89.8721915274811, 35.70013612545617], [-89.87213507698236, 35.70010626328361], [-89.87209699901284, 35.70008335460208], [-89.8720517326649, 35.700056511355974], [-89.87198339027896, 35.7000039361421], [-89.87195155508887, 35.699986627574106], [-89.87187800312785, 35.6999571736435], [-89.87180726112415, 35.6999219033337], [-89.87173965523432, 35.699889843247846], [-89.87165968300405, 35.69984986596781], [-89.87155184088974, 35.69979084225292], [-89.87149962096257, 35.69976662799813], [-89.87144216414863, 35.699736789512635], [-89.87138680828768, 35.699709365828475], [-89.87134884848807, 35.699689739227956], [-89.8713179614712, 35.69967076482287], [-89.87129189804536, 35.69964592601531], [-89.8711827737717, 35.699548102901794], [-89.8710754312201, 35.699511605016866], [-89.87093311088823, 35.699453620080185], [-89.87057553113117, 35.69926797348102], [-89.87052730521194, 35.69924284149631], [-89.87040626944994, 35.699180847353944], [-89.8701745469748, 35.69909274657892], [-89.8698490515185, 35.698888613875106], [-89.86962724892263, 35.69876824394774], [-89.86940343563202, 35.698647923366465], [-89.86921772770108, 35.698551331506096], [-89.86904630930796, 35.698460147719224], [-89.86890459616583, 35.698383039649784], [-89.86873613893881, 35.698290141740856], [-89.86867661284323, 35.698258709108956], [-89.8686221480164, 35.69822797679316], [-89.86861288748801, 35.69822244842243], [-89.86857892464482, 35.69820190451671], [-89.86837253924905, 35.69809019976166], [-89.86834280517296, 35.698075303277115], [-89.8681159479975, 35.69795422992337], [-89.86791646002106, 35.6978382536539], [-89.86779930400341, 35.69777205624534], [-89.86777546061641, 35.69775291293969], [-89.86774735704473, 35.69772730180029], [-89.86772863148565, 35.69771050054819], [-89.86771085280478, 35.69769203368864], [-89.86769286943141, 35.697667823363034], [-89.86767828539627, 35.697654208509704], [-89.86765165911581, 35.69764170183836], [-89.86761612421881, 35.69763351468301], [-89.86755126942586, 35.697621919443726], [-89.867457540738, 35.6975913016322], [-89.86742496638304, 35.69758140171008], [-89.86738316102537, 35.69756679276729], [-89.8673273902921, 35.69755580280083], [-89.86726567137735, 35.69754741779979], [-89.86712364606831, 35.697569599659325], [-89.86700605961994, 35.69758925023644], [-89.86632531278472, 35.69771728344671], [-89.8657487978597, 35.69781985489848], [-89.8653681701784, 35.69788712437757], [-89.86511070256313, 35.69793307999877], [-89.86499874293723, 35.6979525954916], [-89.86491845726916, 35.697965228623794], [-89.8648045751316, 35.69795082598911], [-89.86471828311664, 35.69793323801275], [-89.86468336396334, 35.69790190583287], [-89.86467117685322, 35.697876159097966], [-89.86465711300173, 35.69785045616023], [-89.86464652763088, 35.6978170131166], [-89.86463610656484, 35.69778815997025], [-89.86463136937861, 35.6977607045196], [-89.86461338891102, 35.69773050014675], [-89.86454834397817, 35.69769682289794], [-89.86450062216127, 35.69767498500607], [-89.86443155112791, 35.69763374542281], [-89.86437457200925, 35.6975631155679], [-89.86434263868684, 35.69751026987413], [-89.86418566982698, 35.69726895058513], [-89.86408462505375, 35.697121257993864], [-89.86401132538826, 35.697014259770555], [-89.86397553071825, 35.69695844246894], [-89.86398911493251, 35.69691829694096], [-89.86399712600591, 35.69687981539087], [-89.86401970703722, 35.69682873492618], [-89.86398677374714, 35.696800417776615], [-89.86395781186009, 35.69677813383982], [-89.86392107268561, 35.696748376024566], [-89.86387378969012, 35.696738780288484], [-89.86380510309043, 35.69670825186162], [-89.86377195201142, 35.69667381384934], [-89.86373863562069, 35.69663478594943], [-89.86361471286088, 35.69642484198917], [-89.86359292609353, 35.696393196794915], [-89.86354538352731, 35.696323874000356], [-89.86349414355865, 35.696256171384015], [-89.86341130119781, 35.69614480522062], [-89.86336982476877, 35.6960875908068], [-89.86334975063086, 35.69605131007502], [-89.86334319208699, 35.696025429186946], [-89.86332891000811, 35.695993604377215], [-89.86330298912091, 35.69595133683786], [-89.86325836287784, 35.69591104585858], [-89.86317945980763, 35.69583559089987], [-89.86311313300448, 35.695798109294316], [-89.86302981024312, 35.69576791978707], [-89.86292868611963, 35.69572284663535], [-89.86246712722729, 35.695523317878155], [-89.86225369660266, 35.69543411978586], [-89.86196384125064, 35.69530929891882], [-89.86162632190641, 35.695164168132834], [-89.86157656157125, 35.69513778280074], [-89.86151560046518, 35.69511319609828], [-89.86147753341915, 35.6950987854126], [-89.86143190836762, 35.695083023248884], [-89.86138435304974, 35.69506577481427], [-89.86131765486437, 35.69503826104596], [-89.86124720451379, 35.6950108364985], [-89.86122623965245, 35.69500214488318], [-89.86119181663148, 35.694984584873104], [-89.86111662947742, 35.69492970370925], [-89.86108089249335, 35.694875415363875], [-89.86105950794588, 35.694802406727064], [-89.86106615167162, 35.694725668831786], [-89.86106964596178, 35.69466585165464], [-89.86112763026817, 35.694502122300314], [-89.86124307466567, 35.69426503820185], [-89.86131699483035, 35.694126966717604], [-89.8613972547171, 35.694008654522534], [-89.86146597004209, 35.693935033748645], [-89.8615238117596, 35.69387239324121], [-89.86162844309372, 35.69380557607418], [-89.86191019314339, 35.693703912855234], [-89.86214360676887, 35.693615651182974], [-89.8625598919899, 35.69344339372394], [-89.86345386678384, 35.69308362772079], [-89.86392350744754, 35.69288099405233], [-89.86473983238862, 35.69255523237398], [-89.8649749504176, 35.692462330016355], [-89.86514794455759, 35.69236478105542], [-89.86525024178607, 35.69233783759723], [-89.86612451894143, 35.69211024137098], [-89.86652851891287, 35.6920148438869], [-89.86729094636996, 35.69180981495863], [-89.86754966645421, 35.69174697675232], [-89.86832234126229, 35.69156655521116], [-89.868335436368, 35.6915245579568], [-89.86835285873794, 35.691468679682345], [-89.86831823369812, 35.69145143025808], [-89.86826361393003, 35.691446605856], [-89.86822973832246, 35.69144435111216], [-89.86805787035414, 35.69146836034496], [-89.86788649569274, 35.69150614170977], [-89.86741314745123, 35.69160472906885], [-89.86691000192506, 35.69171014988814], [-89.86615762386117, 35.691881242661836], [-89.86554086810995, 35.692012339423705], [-89.86523027707, 35.69209478694316], [-89.86473936094082, 35.69219943069315], [-89.86442598870602, 35.69227959727711], [-89.86426934482412, 35.69232085227511], [-89.86413010106256, 35.69236638299504], [-89.86393985224709, 35.69242476261949], [-89.86355623252355, 35.69255828788751], [-89.86320811275817, 35.69271198291985], [-89.86247918311864, 35.69298965955626], [-89.8619778722306, 35.693200938242974], [-89.86155743113977, 35.69334227775058], [-89.86140220639012, 35.693423363389904], [-89.86108781386781, 35.69358355583695], [-89.86094675466802, 35.69370270023701], [-89.86088895158831, 35.69376126937999], [-89.86080269265968, 35.69383586319231], [-89.86078288628738, 35.693855864994404], [-89.86072157401813, 35.69386290307783], [-89.8606598621256, 35.693858790997474], [-89.8606079050913, 35.69384049598703], [-89.86056921914668, 35.69381072479323], [-89.86054814679359, 35.69369962416474], [-89.86048310809659, 35.693367831943085], [-89.86043541404206, 35.693239975112625], [-89.86018230925231, 35.692673743891206], [-89.86002698781708, 35.69226935773696], [-89.85991093657569, 35.691917978292146], [-89.85988469215071, 35.6918271368496], [-89.85985245093441, 35.691729400789434], [-89.85985247565722, 35.69164966039979], [-89.85987974635637, 35.691447317369374], [-89.85992257611747, 35.69119769909976], [-89.85993509665592, 35.69114580495295], [-89.85993333853386, 35.6910965954337], [-89.85992287995367, 35.691045247651815], [-89.85990700960134, 35.69100341086113], [-89.8598782281226, 35.690922009338394], [-89.85985460521724, 35.69082406925046], [-89.85980387429404, 35.69069159401691], [-89.85975398068688, 35.690582551947635], [-89.85969733824075, 35.6904455269446], [-89.85967650422461, 35.690345174472235], [-89.85964917136383, 35.69022386942834], [-89.85964169521482, 35.69009505691436], [-89.8596203591496, 35.689980644679295], [-89.85958795175215, 35.689878222192434], [-89.8595714980613, 35.689819980596496], [-89.85956332514327, 35.689752162518495], [-89.85953691456123, 35.68965663373923], [-89.85951184219205, 35.68959859792382], [-89.859466999234, 35.68955041171571], [-89.85936336889455, 35.68946609998077], [-89.85931015845163, 35.68942514980973], [-89.8592630294423, 35.689393436477054], [-89.85915811635293, 35.6893537152267], [-89.85906765020194, 35.68931599562497], [-89.85898817073921, 35.689263942233254], [-89.85891064417727, 35.6891860450327], [-89.85887890754695, 35.68910236922181], [-89.85886973221913, 35.689006430628396], [-89.85889460682114, 35.68889795620487], [-89.85895157845303, 35.688802790589186], [-89.85902807261874, 35.68869074321251], [-89.85907879754221, 35.68858165523103], [-89.8591760648779, 35.688487876858126], [-89.85928794606836, 35.688400787325335], [-89.85940903040718, 35.688329894834], [-89.85956728733649, 35.68825342917391], [-89.85968803640336, 35.6881731638591], [-89.85978859323686, 35.688091034262435], [-89.8598498595411, 35.68803563606246], [-89.85990741652196, 35.687956872918534], [-89.8599511138684, 35.68789251095788], [-89.86000563110773, 35.68780912978191], [-89.8600538157884, 35.68770948233727], [-89.86006321257058, 35.687650626149015], [-89.8600610360617, 35.68758970090654], [-89.8600473710343, 35.68752904792071], [-89.8600371630526, 35.68748473045105], [-89.86001758531364, 35.68741952778284], [-89.85999075550384, 35.687312282484754], [-89.85999697174665, 35.68717558716814], [-89.85998724903769, 35.687094906827525], [-89.8599983293858, 35.687022101158], [-89.86002609500277, 35.686937739126236], [-89.86005495599424, 35.68688404143035], [-89.86008079789453, 35.68684157516081], [-89.86013268198113, 35.68676222037215], [-89.860158324606, 35.686714178099656], [-89.8602446776863, 35.68664237386802], [-89.8604053084906, 35.68654369096356], [-89.8604692358199, 35.686514270777465], [-89.86054712910862, 35.68649288772706], [-89.86060511911957, 35.686488718320284]]]]}}]}
```

Comment: If your goal is to center the view on each polygon, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should be doing `map.gitBounds(fields.getBounds())` instead. Otherwise there's nothing wrong at first sight, and you should show how the GeoJSON representation of `fields` looks like.

Comment: I don't want to center the view on each polygon, but for all polygons that get reported back into the fields Feature Collection.

Comment: Same thing. `fields.getBounds()` will return the bounding box relative to the entire `FeatureCollection`. No need to rely on Turf here. Besides, according to http://www.geojsonlint.com/ , your GeoJSON is invalied due to the polygon winding.